# How to upload a file from a page called already through Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

The form upload works if not called through Ajax first, but if the tab/page is loaded like

```
$.get(page+".php", {type: type}, function(d){ $('#mainContent').html(d); });
```

Then the Malsup jquery plugin doesn't work and will redirect to the url listed in the forms action section.

How do it get it to work the same way if I was directly on that page?

Comment: I believe your problem is with delegation. Can you try running the Malsup plugin directly after `$('#mainContent').html(d);`. This way the plugin will see the new html just added through ajax.

Comment: add more relevant code or jsfiddle

Comment: @AdamMerrifield Ah that sounds about right. I'll try that now.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield That didn't work. Normally that would have sorted that.

Comment: Can you please add a http://jsfiddle.net? There isn't much I can do without seeing more code.

Comment: @Dave What more do you need? The index page is using that $.get to fetch pages when clicked on a tab. One of those pages happens to have the form upload using the Malsup plugin. If I was directly on the tab page then the plug works if its called from the index page then it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I believe on success of ajax request you have to re-bind Malsup plugin so that the DOM gets updated. You would have to add the rebinding in the success handler.This may solve your problem.

Comment: Okay So your first comment is correct, but I have a lame question to follow it though. So What I did to get it to work was after the $('#mainContent').html(d); I added the entire plug code and then the $("#newItem").ajaxForm(options); My question is why do I need to put the whole plugin code there?

Comment: As give above in your ajax. This line $('#mainContent').html(d); --- fills html with response from ajax..and now this new elements which are added as a result are needed to be registered in DOM.

Comment: I dont know any other shortcut approach regarding this, may be other experts here can answer it better, my intent was to make you familiar with issue.